# Connect a cloudwatch alarm to the contents of a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

Utilizing anything within the suite of AWS tools, is there a way to alarm off of the values in a DynamoDB table?

For example, if anything is updated within a DynamoDB table, is there a way I could hook things up so that the contents of the table are checked and if certain values are set in the table, a cloudwatch alarm can alarm off of it?

Note: I need to check the entire contents of the table (won't be a large table) before knowing what to do or whether or not to alarm.

Even just some details about what sort of components of stack that could do this would be helpful!

Comment: I have no time right now to write a proper answer, so I'll just point you to the right direction. You'll need DynamoDB Streams with a Lambda function. See the tutorial here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda to trigger the alarm. The steps are as follows.

- Create an Alarm in CloudWatch.
- For the particular table create a stream to trigger a Lambda function. This will make sure when a change happens in the DynamoDB table, the change will be available to a Lambda Code where you can write the Alarm trigger if the change meets your condition.
- Using [AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#setAlarmState-property) for CloudWatch trigger the Alarm changing its state calling `setAlarmState` method, from Lambda, if the condition is met.

In addition for your usecase, if the need is to send a notification after a certain data changed in a table, you can setup a AWS SNS topic to be triggered from Lambda as follows.

DynamoDB Strams -> Lambda -> SNS Publish

Here subsequent actions can be configured from SNS when a messege is published.

Note: You need to provide CloudWatch permission to the IAM role assumed by the Lambda function to trigger the Alarm.

Comment: If the information provided about a single change isn't enough information to decide whether or not to alarm (if we need to know the contents of the table as a whole - it's not a big table), would we need to read in the table as part of the Lambda function?

Comment: Yes. You need to query the dynamodb table using Lambda function (If you need more data to take the decision other than the change set)

Comment: Thanks. Also, since there is no associated "metric" that I can map the alarm to for CloudWatch, is there a way to just have the alarm not watch any particular metric but just be set into and out of alarm manually?

Comment: As it is now, unfortunately this doesn't provide a complete solution for me as the setAlarmState call is temporary and the alarm resets immediately after. :(

Comment: Hi Mei, setAlarmState is the only approach available to trigger the alarm from code. I didn't know it resets immediately. Sorry for that. By the way did you try SNS? Which is in the latter part of the answer.

Comment: Yes, if we needed SNS it would have worked, but we have an internal tool that actually uses the cloudwatch alarm state so we would need the alarm state to stay on for our purposes